# How to list and manage all IT systems of a company?

Tags: networking, microsoft-excel, administrator, diagrams, visualization

I currently need to document all our IT systems in some sort of list or diagram. I am wondering if an Excel table or something similar is really the best thing to do this. Therefore, I would like to know how if you know a better solution or how do you are keeping track of all the systems in your company.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Really depends on your requirement. You could create an asset register, assuming all the assets have unique hostnames, and then list out the owner, spec, service tag, renewal date, O/S etc... Alternatively, you could use a client-side auditing tool such as Quest's KACE agent to send all the data to you.

Comment: Yeah, thats true. But I'm not sure myself what my requirements are. That's why I've been asking in general how others in your company have handled it. Thanks for the tool suggestion.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should use a monitoring solution like Zabbix ou Nagios, then you can track all of your servers, vm, containers... You can even have interactive maps and mail alerts

You can also use a wiki to detail some important informations.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, I definitely will check that out.